# i18next and api props

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have a component that has been passed an API as a prop. How can I translate my desired API using i18next?

```
import React from "react";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";

const Footer = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{data.about_text_latin}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```